# Dynamic mutate_each in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I have the following columns in my dataframe:

```
c1_sum | c2_sum | d | c1 | c2
```

The columns c# and c#_sum are dynamic. I'm trying to do something like this for all c#:

```
mutate(c#_weight = (d * c#) / c#_sum)
```

The final result would be:

```
c1_sum | c2_sum | d | c1 | c2 | c1_weight | c2_weight
```

I already tried something with *matches* to handle only the column I want, but I don't know how to parse the current column name (c#_weight = (d * c#) / c#_sum).

```
mutate_each(funs(weight = .), matches("^c[0-9]*$", ignore.case=FALSE))
```

**I cannot use *tidyr* because I'm using *sparklyr*!! Is there any way to do it using only dplyr??**

Comment: I cannot use tidyr because I'm using sparklyr!! Is there any way to do it using only dplyr??

Comment: But you can use `stats::reshape`, right?